# Our puzzling friend

Tags: wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle, knowledge

One of our friends spends all of his time on the Puzzling Stack Exchange, so to get him to come out with us, we let him pick what to do. This was a pretty big mistake as we soon found out. This was the invitation he sent all of us:

> An accord
> We've got potatoes, except when we didn't
> Live cat toy
>
> One of the few for java
> Some paid borrowing
> Sometimes on, sometimes off
> To end, put in the coffin
> Freight with a caboose
> This, this never changes
>
> Camelbak has a lifetime of this
> People try to do this to the fullest
> Well known tall rock
> Arthur is one, fun to spell
> A limiting speed
>
> A really big fantasy race
> Mathematicians best friend
> When you aren't seeking
> Not necessary
> Corsets are often this, much to the wearer's dismay
> Hit close to home, but above deletion
> Black where you get baguettes
>
> Make a choice
> Tall wet grass
> The whole kit and caboodle
> Almost a circle, but not
> Purple, but no blue
>
> Some light interrogation
> The head honcho
> Unwanted rarity of game loot
> Uncivil disobedience
> Some say they will rise again
>
> Found in a perverts wall
> Give 4 stars, maybe 3, sometimes 5
> The space between
> Best of the best, well known as 4
> Risk analyzer, often insured
>
> To receive the location, you must first determine the activity
> Enjoy

None of us have any idea what he is talking about, so we thought maybe the place he spends all of his time might be able to find the answer for us.

Oh, and when we asked him to give us a hint, he just keep mumbling about jumbled words within words within words. We thought he had just lost his mind from working on so many puzzles but maybe it is important.

Can you find out what activity our friend has picked for us?

**Hint:** It looks like you are having some trouble, so here is some information about my friend that might help you out. I don't know how much of this will help though! **Edit:** I think I have narrowed down some information about him!

> He lives alone in an apartment and dislikes the monthly cost. He was originally from Texas. He plays a lot of video games, both console/handheld and computer. He doesn't really like the current state of the American government and wishes it didn't exist. He doesn't really like vegetables but thinks fruit is alright.

We really want to find out what he wants to do, so we asked him for another clue. It seems he gave us another puzzle though instead. Maybe to you guys this will be a hint though?

> Short of an inverse explosion
>  It's coming™
>  The internet loves to try to give you this type of advice, also seafood
>
>  Double cheeseburger, large fries, medium root beer no ice
>  Girls these days don't want to be this, female dog association
>  Makes liquid white, red, and even pink

Comment: Does the answer has anything to do with trekking??

Comment: @Abhishek I'm not sure, looks like you will have to solve the puzzle to find out the answer!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first step is to:

> Find words treating each line as a single clue

The next step is to:

> Make words by jumbling the first letters of each word thus obtained
>  Hint 2 gives clues to these words

And finally, of course:

> Make one last word from those

The list:

> An accord - **pact**
>  We've got potatoes, except when we didn't - **Irish (potato famine)**
>  Live cat toy - **mouse** (cats can be quite sadistic :P)
>  --> **IMP**
>
>  One of the few for java - **Eclipse**
>  Some paid borrowing - **rent**
>  Sometimes on, sometimes off - **intermittent**
>  To end, put in the coffin - **nail** (as in, the nail in the coffin)
>  Freight with a caboose - **train**
>  This, this never changes - **war**
>  --> **WINTER**
>
>  Camelbak has a lifetime of this - **guarantee**
>  People try to do this to the fullest - **live life**
>  Well known tall rock - **Everest**
>  Arthur is one, fun to spell - **Aardvark**
>  A limiting speed - **light**
>  --> **LEGAL**
>
>  A really big fantasy race - **giant**
>  Mathematicians best friend - **number**
>  When you aren't seeking - **hiding**
>  Not necessary - **optional**
>  Corsets are often this, much to the wearer's dismay - **tight**
>  Hit close to home, but above deletion - **insert** (key)
>  Black where you get baguettes - **noir**
>  --> **NOTHING**
>
>  Make a choice - **decide**
>  Tall wet grass  - **reed**
>  The whole kit and caboodle - **everything**
>  Almost a circle, but not - **oval**
>  Purple, but no blue - **red**
>  --> **ORDER**
>
>  Some light interrogation - **ask**
>  The head honcho - **boss**
>  Unwanted rarity of game loot - **common**
>  Uncivil disobedience -  **insurrection**
>  Some say they will rise again - **South**
>  --> **BASIC**
>
>  Found in a perverts wall - **peephole**
>  Give 4 stars, maybe 3, sometimes 5 - **rate**
>  The space between - **gap**
>  Best of the best, well known as 4 - **elite** (Top Gun and Pokemon reference)
>  Risk analyzer, often insured  - **actuary**
>  --> **GRAPE**

---

Hint 2:

> Short of an inverse explosion - **IMP** (Short of "implosion") [1st set]
>   It's coming™ - **WINTER** [2nd set]
>   The internet loves to try to give you this type of advice, also seafood - **LEGAL** [3rd set]
>   ____ - **NOTHING** [4th set]
>   Double cheeseburger, large fries, medium root beer no ice - **ORDER** [5th set]
>   Girls these days don't want to be this, female dog association - **BASIC** [6th set]
>   Makes liquid white, red, and even pink - **GRAPE** (Wine) [7th set]

---

Final answer is:

> **BOWLING**

Comment: I have made some small grammar changes that might make some clues less ambiguous

Comment: I was also working on this, but my answers are a little different.I have Ireland instead of Irish, Warranty for the Camelbak clue, Aardvark (I'm sure about this) for Arthur, C (same concept, but I think letters matter) for limiting speed, Red for the purple clue, and Actuary for risk analyzer - just realized this is a community wiki ... editing ..

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but the politically correct name for Ayers Rock is Uluru

Comment: `This, this never changes` This might be "change" itself or quite obvious one, "war" as in fallout quote. Also, to get some vowels there, `One of the few for java` might be "Eclipse".

Comment: I made a small change to the 2nd to last clue to remove some ambiguity, it shouldn't have a big impact overall though

Comment: If `This, this never changes` translates to itself, `this`, we can make the word `TALENT`, but there are just so many possibilities...

Comment: Racing, not raceing

Comment: @Xylius: It seems the answer has to be a 7-letter word.  I know the 6-letter form of the word is the correct spelling, but entering the 7-letter form in an online dictionary did also work - so I assumed it was valid.  (But perhaps that was just the dictionary being smart.)

Comment: FYI none of the words are swear words

Comment: Hmm, until we know for absolute certain, can we not remove words previously suggested as answers? `Imp` may be correct, but then again, so could `Aim` or even `Dim`. But the suggestions were removed, and that's not helpful at all.

Comment: And the blank line in hint 2 confirms NOTHING.

Comment: I have never heard of the "extreme 4", but it looks like you guys are making good progress

Comment: Just noticed the additional edit - seems like we're on the right track, then.

Comment: Top Gun quote: "The **elite**--best of the best"  Doesn't change the letter though.

Comment: The 6th word should be BITCH based on the secondary hint, which means that ASK and SOUTH are wrong.

Comment: I dont get how bowling fits the first hint though... actually I don't get how the first hint helps in any way....

Comment: I showed my friend and he said we got it right! One thing he pointed out was that "some light interrogation" was interview and "uncivil disobedience" was anarchy, otherwise you got all of his clues! Also he noted that the first hint was to help lead us in the right direction with the clues, not the overall answer

Comment: @Bobson girls these days avoid being a "basic bitch" ... therein lies the association to the female dog.

Comment: @Matt - Interesting.  Slang continues evolving, I suppose.  That also explains why I couldn't think of an alternative to SOUTH.