# Our puzzling friend 2: Electric Puzzaloo

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

Thank you guys for helping us figure out what activity my friend wanted to do [over here!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/32263/our-puzzling-friend)
Unfortunately the puzzles didn't stop there. When we asked him to give us the location of where he wanted to go, he gave us this instead:

```
Lorem  ipsum
vestibulum  elementum sapien  quis pulvinar

Quisque  et hendrerit neque suspendisse

Ut leo lectus lacinia

Pellentesque  sagittis  ultrices tortor at vulputate
```

---

```
In euismod massa
proin a  risus a

Pellentesque  id nisi eu elit
morbi pharetra  massa risus

Donec  aliquet quam non dignissim
vivamus interdum

Nam  vulputate  nisi ultricies justo scelerisque
nam aliquet luctus leo vitae  porta
```

This seemed even harder to solve than his first puzzle, since to us it just looks like some randomly generated text. To get some progress we asked him for a hint and he said:

> 2016 A Space Journey

We asked him if he meant the movie 2001 A Space Odyssey and he just replied:

> Never heard of it, but I do watch The Green Mile periodically

We are at a complete loss for this one, maybe you guys can help us out again?

Comment: Looks like the number of spaces between the words may be significant.

Comment: Are the spaces on the ends of the lines significant or for PSE formatting?

Comment: @LeppyR64 PSE formatting, but have been removed since it was a code block, thanks for catching that

Comment: Is it NORTH KOREA your looking for!? They had a satellite launch in 2016!!

Comment: @BipinChandra What was the satellite's name?  It might fill in my blanks :)

Comment: @LeppyR64 KwangMyongSong-4

Comment: @BipinChandra What is North Korea? I've never heard anything about it

Comment: @BipinChandra Yeah, that's another blank from me too :)

Comment: @GordonAllocman  it's a country where dictatorship prevails!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

He's going Bowling at:

> [Bowl-A-Roll](http://www.bowl-a-roll.com/) at [43°5'16N 77°35'4W](https://www.google.com/maps/place/43%C2%B005'16.0%22N+77%C2%B035'04.0%22W/@43.0877778,-77.5844444,19z/data=!3m1!1e3)

The biggest hint for me was when I saw the text

> Lorem Ipsum - Which commonly indicates filler text.  So the words didn't matter.

continuing to read the hints at the bottom confirmed it.

> The first clue tells us to look at the spaces.  The second clue refers to [David Morse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Morse_(actor)) an actor in the Green Mile and indicates that the spaces refer to Morse Code.

Converting:

> the lines to the numbers of spaces between words and converting 2 to dashes and 1 to dots gives us:
> T -   2
> C -   2   1   2   1
>
> B -   2   1   1   1
>
> S -   1   1   1
>
> 7 -   2   2   1   1   1
>
>
> I -   1   1
> R -   1   2   1
>
> B -   2   1   1   1
> R -   1   2   1
>
> B -   2   1   1   1
> E -   1
>
> 7 -   2   2   1   1   1
> 4 -   1   1   1   1   2

Yielding:

> `TC B S 7`
> `IR BR BE 74`

Thanks to F'', the next hint was the usage of the word "Periodically" in the second hint.  Converting the letters to their elemental number and the elemental numbers to their elements yields:

> `43 5 16 N`
>  `77 35 4 W`

These coordinates point to the final destination as listed above.

Comment: Great update, now has everything I was looking for! Accepted